# Computing the limit of a kind of "mean value" iteration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be real number, and define a kind of "mean value" iteration like
$$
x_i^{(k+1)} = \frac{x_i^{(k)}+x_{i+1}^{(k)}}{2}, i=1,\dotsc,n,\quad x_{n+1}^{(k)} = x_1^{(k)},k=0,1,2,\dotsc
$$
and $x_i^{(0)} = x_i,i=1,2,\dotsc,n$, this is a consequence saying that
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} x_i^{(k)} = \frac{1}{n}(x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n}),\quad i=1,\dotsc,n.
$$
An advanced calculus shows that this is equivalent to prove
$$
\lim_{k\to+\infty} \sum_{s=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-i}{n} \right\rfloor} \frac{1}{2^k} \binom{k}{sn+i} = \frac{1}{n}, \quad i=1,\dotsc,n.
$$
But I do not know how to deal with the sum. Can any fellow help? That will be so nice for a help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection#Binomial_theorem

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. This technique is surprisingly helpful.

Comment: today i posted he same question asking for the source.i have seen an elegant solution to it in some book but I do not remember.could anybody kindly help

Comment: @AgnostMystic I have translated my answer into English. You could check it for a second.

Comment: @YOTAL ,lots of thanks for taking time to post this beautiful  answer

Answer (score 0):

For a formal power series
$$
f(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2} + \cdots + a_{m}x^{m} + \dotsb
$$
and one extract its $n$-step portion as
$$
f_{n,i} = a_{i}x^{i} + a_{n+i}x^{n+i} + \cdots + a_{kn+i}x^{kn+i} + \dotsb.
$$
The core mechanism is to express $f_{n,i}$ in terms of $f$ which is called "Simpson methods" or "series multisection". In fact if one denotes
$\omega_{n} = e^{\frac{2\pi\sqrt{-1}}{n}}$ as $n$-th primitive root of unit then $f_{n,i}$ can be expressed as
$$
f_{n,i}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\omega_{n}^{-iq}f(\omega_{n}^{q}x) \quad \tag{1}\label{444380_1}
$$
Below is the proof of \eqref{444380_1}. Using property of root of unit
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\omega_{n}^{-iq}f(\omega_{n}^{q}x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}a_{m}\omega_{n}^{(m-i)q}x^{m}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\omega_{n}^{(m-i)q}}{n}a_{m}x^{m}\\
 = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\mathbf{1}_{n\mathbb{Z}+i}(m)a_{m}x^{m} = f_{n,i}
$$
So \eqref{444380_1} is derived. Then by \eqref{444380_1} and binomial theorem $(1+x)^{k} = \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}\binom{k}{i}x^{i}$,setting $n$-step partition and $x = 1$ one gets
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k-i}{n}\rfloor}\frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{k}{sn+i} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\omega_{n}^{-iq}(\frac{1+\omega_{n}^{q}}{2})^{k} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\omega_{2n}^{-2iq}\cos^{k}(\frac{q\pi}{n})\omega_{2n}^{kq} \\
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{q=0}^{q=n-1}\cos{\frac{(k-2i)q\pi}{n}}\cos^{k}(\frac{q\pi}{n}),\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}^+
$$

one lets $k \to +\infty$ to derive terms of $q\neq 0$ tend to zero, and term of $q=0$ tends to $1$ that is
$$
\lim_{k\to+\infty}\sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k-i}{n}\rfloor}\frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{k}{sn+i}=\frac{1}{n} \quad i=1,\dotsc,n.
$$

Comment: Can you translate this to English so that it can be read by more people? The Chinese language version will be stored in the edit history, so it won't be lost.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Alright. I have translated this answer to English. It will be great if this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated